# How can I refresh my external data source (link to sharepoint) in Access vba?

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, vba

Really struggling to find a solution to this.
I have an access form, which has a subform. 
The subform displays, via a query, records from an external data source (a sharepoint folder). I need the external link to refresh automatically, ideally on load.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    TableDefs![My External Table Name].RefreshLink
End Sub
```

didn't work neither did it without `TableDefs!`

I'm piecing things together with limited experience, this is my first dabble with access. I had the connection refresh off a macro in excel with

```
Sub Refresh_click()
    Range("MyExternalTableName[[#Headers],[ID]]").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End Sub
```

and that was fine, now in access I'm lost. I need this subform to be updated before using the rest of the form but could refresh off a button if needs be. I already use a refresh button as part of the form and this doesn't affect the external link unfortunately.

Comment: If it is a linked table, you can try `CurrentDb.TableDefs("My External Table Name").RefreshLink`

Comment: Any time you query the data in an external data source, Access pulls the most up to date information automatically, there is no reason to manually update the underlying data source connection. Instead you need to tell your subform to requery the data. This can be done by setting a macro on the subform’s OnTimer event to Requery itself every 5 seconds, for example.